# How to display maths symbol but not ignore the space?

Tags: spacing, environments, verbatim, math-operators

[image]

I want to display like that but my code seems like not work.
when I trying to display inline math it will ignore spaces but when I trying to put them into a verbatim environment it will ignore the math symbol.

Comment: If you want help with your code you need to show some code, preferably a small complete document  as text (use the `{}` in the editor to mark it as a code section)

Comment: Try insert a empty minipage with appropriate width on the left

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Math mode ignores spaces. With `\usepackage{amsmath}` you can use `\text{For }` (note the trailing space) and `\text{ is reflexive}` to temporarily switch to text mode. Also, `mod` should be `\bmod` It is an operator, not a product of `m`, `o` and `d`. The `verbatim` issue depends on how you are doing that. So, It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

Comment: @Peter Grill: I suppose you mean `\pmod`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item By definition $[x \sim y] \longleftrightarrow [6 \mid 4x+2y]
  \longleftrightarrow [4x+2y \equiv 0 \pmod{6}]$
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item For reflexivity
    \begin{gather*}
      \forall x \in \mathbb{Z} :
      4x+2x \equiv 6x \equiv 0\cdot x \equiv 0 \pmod{6} \\
      \therefore [x \sim x]
      \implies \forall x [x \in \mathbb{Z}] [x \sim x]
    \end{gather*}
    Therefore $\sim$ is reflexive.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]